# Install opencv on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know we can install opencv on ec2 linux version by running some command lines. However, now I want to deploy my j2ee web app on elastic beanstalk directly from either eclipse(run on the eb tomcat server) or create new app on eb console by upload a .war file. But in my web project, I am using opencv/javacv library, so when I try to run it on elastic beanstalk, it gives me the error:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
```

so i'm confused about how to install opencv into my elastic beanstalk environment so that I can run my app on the cloud server.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? I'm also having trouble with this, albeit with Python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725954/how-to-install-opencv-python-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score -2):

I am new to beanstalk, but it just seems it is not setting your native requirements properly. Remember that javacv is a layer on top of native OpenCV, so you must have dll/so for the native platform properly installed, and it just seems that beanstalk isn't doing it for you.