# How to install opencv-python on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been developing a Python application locally, and now want to deploy it to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, but I have hit the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking opencv-python==2.4.8.1 (from -r
/opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 12))  
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python==2.4.8.1
(from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 12))

Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external opencv-python to allow). 
Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for opencv-python==2.4.8.1 
(from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 12))
```

If I connect with SSH and type `sudo pip install opencv-python` it says "Downloading/unpacking opencv-python" for a minute or so, then:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for opencv-python
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I also tried adding "http://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/o/opencv-python-2.4.9-3.fc22.x86_64.rpm" to my requirements.txt but that failed as follows:

```
Downloading/unpacking http://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/o/opencv-python-2.4.9-3.fc22.x86_64.rpm (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 14))
  Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-ONBFer-unpack/opencv-python-2.4.9-3.fc22.x86_64.rpm (downloaded from /tmp/pip-SUUfnS-build, content-type: application/x-rpm); cannot detect archive format
Cleaning up...
Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-SUUfnS-build
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I also tried "sudo yum install opencv-python" but that failed as follows:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/2014.09                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/2014.09                                     | 2.3 kB     00:00
No package opencv-python available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

For my development system I got the installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. How can I get it installed on EB, please?

If there's no way to install this exact package, what is the best alternative, please?

Comment: I think there is no package `opencv-python` in Python package index.

Comment: Check this link : https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=opencv&submit=search

Comment: Is it not one of these? http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=opencv-python

Comment: that is same. But it is in fedora repository right? not the python package index. To install that, you should use `yum install opencv-python` on a fedora machine. Not `pip install`.

Comment: I've tried that, and have updated my question with the results. I guess it's not a Fedora machine.

Comment: `sudo yum install opencv-python` fails because aws uses its own repos. 
Then requirements.txt takes only python projects which mean basically a directory/archive/git repo... with a setup.py file inside.
You should try : 
`sudo yum install http://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/o/opencv-python-2.4.9-3.fc22.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: OK, that just says "Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Error: Nothing to do"

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options if you are able to consider workarounds.

**With AWS Elastic Beanstalk**

- AWS EB supports Windows Server 2012 and 2008

  Since your installer appears to be a Windows executable, you might consider deploying on Windows.
  https://aws.amazon.com/net/
- Use Docker to package Fedora platform to run on EB's AMI Linux host.

  Elastic Beanstalk supports Docker.
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

  Here is an example of a Docker buildfile for opencv on python.
  https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ibotdotout/python-opencv/

**Without AWS Elastic Beanstalk**

- Other Linux distribution

  If you don't absolutely require Elastic Beanstalk, what about running Fedora?
  These installation instructions are straightforward.

  http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html
  (basically   yum install numpy opencv*  )

  You can use EC2 without Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you. Windows is probably an option, but it is more expensive than Linux, so unless it's impossible or very difficult I'd prefer to stick with Linux. And although I'm not 100% committed to Elastic Beanstalk, its simplicity does appeal to me. Docker looks interesting, but won't install on my 32-bit Windows development computer... I think my next step is probably to try to find a replacement for opencv-python that will install on Amazon Linux. Other suggestions still welcome, though!

Answer (score 1):

The easy workaround for now, is to install pip 1.2.1, which does not require SSL:

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz
cd pip-1.2.1
python setup.py install
```

Maybe that can help you

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it still says "Downloading/unpacking opencv-python
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python
No distributions at all found for opencv-python"

Answer (score 0):

I am running OpenCV with Python support on Amazon EC2 on dedicated instances of Ubuntu 14.04.  I had to install and compile from source to get a reliable stack with python.